# How can I change the default filter for telerik mvc grid?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How can I set the "Starts with" value to be the default filter for telerik asp.net mvc grid?

**UPDATE**: When the user clicks the filter button, I want the "Starts With" option to be his first option, and not the "Is equal to".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to apply default StartsWith filter on initial grid load? If so, the bottom lines of [this help article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-filtering.html) might help.

Comment: When the user clicks the filter button, I want the "Starts With" option to be his first option, and not the "Is equal to".

Comment: Sorry, not smart enough to give you code how to do that or say whether this is possible. Contact Telerik using their forum or support system, they should be able to give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {        
        $('body').find(".t-filter").click(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".t-filter-operator").each(function () {
                    $(this).val("substringof");
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```